# Trying to edit an XML document with a dynamic variable from PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to edit an XML document using PHP, but it does not seem to work, wonder where I am going wrong!

I am trying to do it the following way which I found online. Can anyone please show me the right direction?

**XML**

```
<gold>
    <coin>
        <id>1</id>
        <title>Gold Coin 50 Grams</title>
        <price>500 rupees</price>
        <dimension>20 MM</dimension>
        <thumb_url>http://animsinc.com/Expertise-media.png</thumb_url>
    </coin>
    <coin>
        <id>2</id>
        <title>Gold Coin 50 Grams</title>
        <price>500 rupees</price>
        <dimension>20 MM</dimension>
        <thumb_url>
            http://animsinc.com/Expertise-media.png</thumb_url>
    </coin>
    ...
</gold>
```

**PHP Code**

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->loadXml($str);
$events = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("coin");
foreach($events as $event){
    $eventNames = $event->getElementsByTagName("price");
    $eventN = $eventNames->item(0)->nodeValue;
    if('500' == $eventN){ // ** Failed here, instead of '500',
       // I used '500 rupees' and it worked, as that matches the original text.**
        $eventNames->item(0)->nodeValue = $rest ;
    }
}
var_dump($xmlDoc->saveXML());
```

Here's the desired result. Notice how I've changed the price tag to 2495 rupees.

```
 <gold>
    <coin>
        <id>1</id>
        <title>Gold Coin 50 Grams</title>
        <price>2495 rupees</price>
        <dimension>20 MM</dimension>
        <thumb_url>http://animsinc.com/Expertise-media.png</thumb_url>
    </coin>
    <coin>
        <id>2</id>
        <title>Gold Coin 50 Grams</title>
        <price>2495 rupees</price>
        <dimension>20 MM</dimension>
        <thumb_url>
            http://animsinc.com/Expertise-media.png</thumb_url>
    </coin>
    ...
</gold>
```

Comment: We appreciate your effort to adhere to the question guidelines, but your justification is not actually part of the question so I've removed it, updated your question slightly, upvoted it, and voted to keep it open.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the question again and I think now it is up-to the mark. Thanks a ton for the support, this community is very vibrant and I love it more than Facebook, for that matter SO is the internet for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick solution based on [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php):

```
$gold = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach ($gold->coin as $coin) {
    $coin->price = str_replace('500', $rest, (string) $coin->price);
}

echo $gold->asXML();
```

#### [Working demo](https://eval.in/39098).

Comment: Thanks mate, I figured it out and I really appreciate your help!

Comment: What if I have to update multiple price elements of different coins with different values?

Comment: In that case you'll have to adapt the instruction that replaces the `coin` node value according to the new conditions. I advise you to ask a new question with a XML example that show that new problem.

Comment: I overcame it with my previous code! Just added if conditions there, changed the node values according to my need! :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh hey, it was a mistake on my part, the function works perfect, instead of

```
     if('500' == $eventN)
```

***The Correct woulld be***

```
     if('500 rupees' == $eventN)
```

***Dumb***